# How to open specific file from atom?

Tags: atom-editor

How do i open a specific file from atom. I have  in laravel master.blade.php and I want to put shortcut CTRL-1 for example and open it.I use now advanced-open-file but I want something faster because I all the time name some files the same. Is there a plugin for that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Add command

Add the following to your `init.coffee` (**File > Init Script…**)

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor',
  'open:master-blade': (event) ->
    atom.workspace.open('path/to/master.blade.php')
```

See available options for [`atom.workspace.open`](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.28.2/Workspace#instance-open)

### 2. Add shortcut

Now add the following to `keymap.cson`  (**File > Keymap…**)

```
'.editor:not(.mini)':
  'ctrl+1': 'open:master-blade'
```

**Note:** You can use Atom's built-in [`keybinding-resolver`](https://atom.io/packages/keybinding-resolver) to make sure the shortcut isn't used by one of your installed packages.

Comment: idleberg nice i am adrian you help me :)

Comment: Just for an update: anyone facing an issue with the path in windows, do try using an absolute path with double backward slashes (Worked for me, was getting the error 'invalid escape sequence at \utils' when using single slashes, My Path: C:\\Users\\WasitShafi\\Desktop\\utils\\todos.md). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. In **Ubuntu** you can do this things following below steps...

> 1. Open the terminal.
> 2. Go to the folder of your project.
> 3. Enter command `atom ./<path_of_the_file>`
> 4. If you want to open whole project then enter `atom .`
> 5. Atom will open that file.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: OP asked how to open specific file **from atom**.